# Shopify Webhooks Transaction id

Tags: transactions, shopify, webhooks

Is there any way to get the transaction id from the payment gateway?

I use a rails app which goes to Shopify for payment. How do I get the "transaction id"  from the payment gateway to my rails app.

Does webhooks "order/payment" have this information.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the http://api.shopify.com/transactions.html API – each order has many transactions in Shopify, and that’s where that kind of information ends up (likely in the `receipt` field).